# Robolectric Resources$NotFoundException can't find library (aar) resources

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-resources, robolectric

I have looked quite a bit for a solution for this (few days) and have not come to a solution yet. Basically, for my unit tests using Robolectric, I keep getting Resources$NotFoundException when trying to inflate resources from a dependency (pulled in as an aar). Heres the setup:

build.gradle (project level)

```
// Top Level
buildscript {
    apply from: "${System.getenv('MY_REPOS')}", to: buildscript
    println("REPOS: ${repositories.names}")
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.me.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    testOptions {
        animationsDisabled true
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.me.android:thewidget:4.0.0' // pulled from private repo

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:27.0-jre") {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'failureaccess'
    }

    //UnitTests
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:android-all:9-robolectric-4913185-2'
}
```

I am using `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip` in my gradle-wrapper.properties

and my gradle properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources = true //tried with and without this set
android.enableAapt2 = false // same here with and without this here
```

Then its the default blank activity template that comes in `Android Studio 4.1.2`. So the only thing touched is the main main activity:

```
package com.me.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.me.thewidget.MyOtherView;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void testDialogSetup() {
        MyOtherView myView = new MyOtherView(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

So the issue is with the `MyOtherView` and when it inflates the view inside this class. So in `MyOtherView` it throws the exception in the test when it hits this line:

```
...
inflater.inflate(layout.my_view, this);
...
```

As for the test itself:

```
package com.me.myapplication;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 * Example local unit test, which will execute on the development machine (host).
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ExampleUnitTest {

    MainActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).get();
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
        activity.testDialogSetup(); // not doing anything yet since it throws the error here
    }
}
```

I've tried invalidating/restarting, clearing cache, I've tried different versions of gradle build tools and with the distribution. Everything I read shows to just have the `includeAndroidResources` flag set to true but I have that, and I have already tried with/without `enableUnitTestBinaryResources`  as well as `enableAapt2` ...

ANY help is appreciated since I have been killing myself trying to get this working. I would think its something simple but... I'm lost here. Its like it can't see the dependency (com.me.android:thewidget:4.0.0, MyOtherView) resources at all.

Comment: Adding a bump to my question

Comment: adding another bump to my question

Comment: yet again, another bump**

Comment: What happens if you add `testImplementation 'com.me.android:thewidget:4.0.0'` to your build.gradle and try again?

Comment: problem has been discovered and posted below. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright all, I figured it out (actually a colleague did). I added the robolectric.properties file to the src/test/resources area. in the file I had to put:

```
sdk=28
qualifiers=w1004dp-h654dp
```

I hope this helps someone down the road.